# Ruby on Rails SQLite3 Table ID numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I am practicing with "Rails: Up and Running" book. There is written that database fills id attributes by itself if not added. Here's an example.

some_items.yml:

```
one:
  name: stringOne

two:
  name: stringTwo
```

Ok. Now, I'm making migration and loading data with "rake db:migrate" and "rake db:fixtures:load".
Then I am trying to check what table "some_items" contains. While sending SQL query to SQLite3 console I'm receiving output like this:

```
298486374|stringTwo|2015-04-06 14:00:33|2015-04-06 14:00:33
980190962|stringOne|2015-04-06 14:00:33|2015-04-06 14:00:33
```

I am wondering is SQLite3 fills ID with random numbers? And if so, why not in normal ascending order like 1, 2, ...? And again - if so, why Rails doesn't create ID attribute in YAML testing files to show it in proper order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering is SQLite3 fills ID with random numbers?

No, Rails is doing it.

> And if so, why not in normal ascending order like 1, 2, ...?

I believe that Rails does it for fixture in order to be as much platform-independent as possible and keep it simple.

> And again - if so, why Rails doesn't create ID attribute in YAML testing files to show it in proper order?

If you want to have sequencial IDs, you can have them in your fixtures files:

```
one:
  id: 1
  name: stringOne

two:
  id: 2
  name: stringTwo
```